# Why was the inclusion of differentials necessary here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

A question from JEE Advanced 2k19 goes like this:

> Consider a spherical gaseous cloud of mass density $\rho(r)$ in free space where $r$ is the radial distance from its center. The gaseous cloud is made of particles of equal mass $m$ moving in circular orbits around the common center with the same kinetic energy $K$. The force acting on the particles is their mutual gravitational force. If $\rho(r)$ is constant in time, the particle number density $n(r)=\rho(r)/m$ is: [Correct Answer] $\frac{K}{2\pi r^2m^2G}$

The total mass $M$ of the gas cloud should act as if all of its mass inside the inner radius is concentrated at the center, right? So what I'm doing is I'm equating Newton's universal gravitational force equation to the centripetal force keeping the gas particles orbiting in circular paths around the center. In short:
$$\frac{GMm}{r^2}=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$

Also, since we need to see $v$ out of our equation, I set $mv^2=2K$.
$$\frac{GMm}{r^2}=\frac{2K}{r}\quad\text{or}\quad M=\frac{2Kr}{Gm}$$

What then happens is most interesting, and is where my main problem lies. I set $M=\rho V$, and $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$. After some algebraic manipulations, and also after setting $\rho=mn$, this is what I got: $$n=\frac{3K}{2\pi r^2m^2G}$$

...Which is not the correct answer. The correct answer is derived like this:
$$M=\frac{2Kr}{Gm}\quad\text{or}\quad \mathrm{d}M=\frac{2K}{Gm}\ \mathrm{d}r$$

Then, setting $\mathrm{d}M=\rho\mathrm{d}V$ and $\mathrm{d}V=4\pi r^2\mathrm{d}r$, and pulling off some algebraic maneuvers, the correct answer is derived:
$$n=\frac{K}{2\pi r^2m^2G}$$

I have issues with this solution. Where did I go wrong? Why was the inclusion of differentials necessary here?

Comment: By taking $M=\rho V$ you have assumed a constant (in space) density .

Comment: @NDewolf Which is not the case here? But the question did say, $\rho(r)$ is constant in time?

Comment: Yes its constant in time, so no $t$-dependence, but this says nothing about any $r$-dependence.

Comment: @NDewolf If that's the case then, piece of cake!
Thank you, kind sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$\rho(r)$ is constant in time" does not imply that $\rho(r)$ is a constant function. What it means is that for any given $r_0$, $\rho(r_0)$ does not change with time. Concisely put, $\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\rho(r,t)=0$. Now, since $\rho(r)$ isn't presumably constant throughout the sphere, the constant density case $M=\rho V$ is no longer valid. We must take $\mathrm{d}M=\rho\mathrm{d}V$.

Answer (score 0):

You write;"The total mass  of the gas cloud should act as if all of it is concentrated at the center, right?" No, this is wrong.
In every sphere the gravitational force at some radius R is only dependent of the mass in r<R, the masses outside of r  i.e, r>R do not contribute to the gravity at R.
So you start with a wrong concept.

Comment: While your point is correct, does your A really answer the question?

Comment: I think it did? why not?

Comment: @trula Thanks for pointing out! Will correct that part right away!